# Select from IEnumerable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable

I have a method that returns an object from cache which I use to populate selectlists within the system.

```
var r = CacheHelper.GetCacheItem(...);
return new SelectList((IEnumerable)r, "Id", "Name");
```

`r` is of type `System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType39<string,int,string>>`

By using `IEnumerable enumerable = (IEnumerable)r;` I see that
`enumerable` looks like this:

```
[0]: { Name = "Lost", Id = 1, Area = null }
[1]: { Name = "Found", Id = 2, Area = null }
[2]: { Name = "Stock Adjustment", Id = 3, Area = null }
...
```

I would like to be able to use LINQ toquery the result set to return a subset, while keeping the full list in memory. Something like:

```
var s = enumerable.Where(x => x.Area == "myarea");
```

Answers to similar SO questions suggest using ToList(), but I can't call any LINQ methods on `enumerable` without getting a `System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'..` error message. (I'm using ToList() elsewhere in the code so I have a valid reference to `System.Linq`.

Comment: You're losing the type of the elements through your cast to `IEnumerable`. Is it an option to make `SelectList` generic as well, so that it keeps the type of its elements?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using an anonymous type. Is it possible for you to create a class for your SelectList entries?

Comment: IEnumerable simple doesnt have the Linq-Extensionmethod 'ToList'. This is implemented for IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: Did you try just `r.Where(x => x.Area == "myarea").ToList()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally, you should keep the type information all the way through the system - and potentially create a *named* type with the relevant properties. You could then cast back to `IEnumerable<SomeConcreteType>` later.

If you can't do that though, and assuming you're using C# 4 and .NET 4 or later, you could use dynamic typing:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> enumerable = (IEnumerable<dynamic>) r;
...
var s = enumerable.Where(x => x.Area == "myarea");
```